# Alternative to show intersection of two languages is empty

Tags: formal-languages

Consider our alphabet set is $\Sigma$. Suppose $L\subseteq\Sigma^*$.
I want to show $L \cap L\Sigma^+=\emptyset$ as one of the bellow options:

1. $x,xy\in L\implies y=\lambda$
2. $x,xy^2\in L\implies y=\lambda$

I think the first is true but I have no idea to show that the second is false.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take $\Sigma = \{a\}$ and $L = \{\lambda, a\}$. Then $L$ satisfies (2) but not (1).

Comment: Could you explain more about how your counter example works?

Comment: @Steven Suppose $\Sigma=\{a\}$ and $L=\{\lambda,a,aa\}$ then $L\cap L\Sigma^+\neq \emptyset$, consequently if we choose $x=\lambda$ and $y=a$ then the option 2 will be incorrect! Could you correct me?